# declare @decimal decimal(4,3) = 10.0

Tags: sql-server, decimal

can anyone please tell me why this : declare @decimal decimal(4,3) = 10 gaves me an error in SQL SERVER :

> msg 8115 level 16 state 8 line 1 arithmetic overflow error converting int to data type numeric

even this declare @decimal decimal(4,3) = 10.0 gave this error :

> msg 8115 level 16 state 8 line 1 arithmetic overflow error converting numeric to data type numeric

thanks in advance

Comment: possible duplicate of [SQL Server cast fails with arithmetic overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2884091/sql-server-cast-fails-with-arithmetic-overflow)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A decimal(4,3) has 4 digits in total, with 3 after the decimal point. See [decimal and numeric](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187746.aspx) in the SQL Server online docs, particularly around precision and scale.

It will hold values from -9.999 to +9.999. To support the value 10 you could use a decimal(5,3).

Comment: thanks for your answer but still cant understand , so what value can i gave my variable for this to work ?

Comment: You can give it 1.000

Answer (score 1):

As answered by Rhys a decimal(m,n) can store a total of m digits with n digits to the right of the decimal place.

So Decimal(4,3) has a possible range of values of -9.999 through to +9.999  that is 4 digits in total, 3 to the right of the decimal place. to store 10 you must use Decimal(5,3) but this would allow values upto 99.999

Comment: please add your comment as an answer on my Q so I can accept it!